# Mixpanel people tracking not working

Tags: android, kotlin, mixpanel

I am trying to make Mixpanel people tracking to work but with no success. I see in the logs, that a `create alias event` is sent but in the Mixpanel console no user profile is created.

Also this is code from the demo app in which I managed to replicate the issue, I can't share code from original app due to confidentiality reasons.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mixpanel: MixpanelAPI

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, "mytoken")
    mixpanel.people.set("open date", Date())
    mixpanel.identify(mixpanel.distinctId)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initCustomer()
    postToMixpanel("TEST EVENT")
    MPLog.setLevel(MPLog.VERBOSE)
}

fun initCustomer() {
    mixpanel.alias("1", mixpanel.distinctId)
    val map = listOfNotNull(
            "\$name" to "Nikola",
            "Gender" to "Male",
            "Attraction" to "Girls",
            "Account type" to "WTF",
            "\$email" to "mail@mail.com"
    ).toMap()
    mixpanel.people.setMap(map)
    mixpanel.flush()
}

fun postToMixpanel(eventId: String, additionalProps: Map<String, Any>? = null) {
    val props = JSONObject()
    additionalProps?.let {
        for ((key, value) in it) {
            props.put(key, value)
        }
    }
    mixpanel.track(eventId, props)
}
}
```

These are mixpanel logs from create alias event, I can not see any special property in there such as `$name` and `$email`.

> ```
>  [{
> "event": "$create_alias",
> "properties": {
>     "mp_lib": "android",
>     "$lib_version": "5.4.1",
>     "$os": "Android",
>     "$os_version": "8.1.0",
>     "$manufacturer": "UMIDIGI",
>     "$brand": "UMIDIGI",
>     "$model": "A1_PRO",
>     "$google_play_services": "available",
>     "$screen_dpi": 320,
>     "$screen_height": 1344,
>     "$screen_width": 720,
>     "$app_version": "1.007-staging",
>     "$app_version_string": "1.007-staging",
>     "$app_release": 15,
>     "$app_build_number": 15,
>     "$has_nfc": false,
>     "$has_telephone": true,
>     "$carrier": "m:tel",
>     "$wifi": true,
>     "$bluetooth_enabled": false,
>     "$bluetooth_version": "ble",
>     "token": "",
>     "Has Credit": "False",
>     "Amount of Credits": "0",
>     "time": 1530099794,
>     "distinct_id": "b8769eeb-6a3b-4692-8973-261f9933537e",
>     "alias": "260",
>     "original": "b8769eeb-6a3b-4692-8973-261f9933537e"
> },
> "$mp_metadata": {
>     "$mp_event_id": "43f9c3402ffa6f4c",
>     "$mp_session_id": "c35a49a17d3b9de6",
>     "$mp_session_seq_id": 0,
>     "$mp_session_start_sec": 1530099793
> }
> }]
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling **identify()** method on the people object. It should create a user in Mixpanel.

```
mixpanel.people.identify(mixpanel.getDistinctId());
```

after

```
mixpanel.alias("1", mixpanel.distinctId)
```

in your fun `initCustomer()` method.

Example:

```
fun initCustomer() {
    mixpanel.alias("1", mixpanel.distinctId)
    mixpanel.people.identify(mixpanel.getDistinctId());
    val map = listOfNotNull(
            "\$name" to "Nikola",
            "Gender" to "Male",
            "Attraction" to "Girls",
            "Account type" to "WTF",
            "\$email" to "mail@mail.com"
    ).toMap()
    mixpanel.people.setMap(map)
    mixpanel.flush()
}
```

More info in the android documentation in the section: Managing user identity

https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android